# guess the word game in python - how to mask a word (eg. ------)

Tags: python

I'm writing a guess the word game in python. It's for my school project. I'm almost done, I just have a problem with one thing. I can't figure out how to mask a word. For example, if the word is monkey, the program should display ------ and as the user guess a letter, let's say k, the program should display ---k--

Unfortunately I have to write the code it certain way. I'm supposed to have a main function that will just call other functions that will do all the work (like functions that will ask user for a letter or check if the guessed word is correct). I have finished all the functions except for this masking function.

The function is called `maskWord(state, word, guess)`. I have to keep those variables, but they will be passed to the function. `state` is the masked word (eg.------),`word` is the word to be guessed (eg. monkey) and `guess` is the letter guessed by the user. Once the function updates the masked word, it should return `state`. The other rule is I can't create global variables. The variables that are passed are the ones that have to be used.

Here's what I have:

```
def maskWord(state, word, guess)
  guessed = []
  guessed.append(guess)
  for guess in word:
    if guess in guessed:
      state += guess
    else: state += "-"
  return state
```

It doesn't really work. Because my main function that calls this function is a while loop, each time `guessed` becomes an empty string.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. I know that it has to be possible to write this function using only the variables, because my teacher only allowed to use those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed my answer to reflect comments, it's somewhat shorter then what **kjtl**'s answer is. But it's based on the same concept, by using state as... well, current state :)

```
def maskWord(state, word, guess):
    state = list(state)
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == guess:
             state[i] = guess
    return "".join(state)


# Lets test if it works..:
word = "electricity"
state = "-" * len(word)
tries = 0

play = True
while play:
    if tries == len(word)*2: 
        print "Fail..."; 
        play = False
    guess = raw_input("Guess: ")
    tries +=1
    state = maskWord(state, word, guess)
    print state
    if maskWord(state, word, guess) == word:  
        print "WIN, WIN!!"; 
        play = False
```

Comment: Needs an exit condition when matched.

Comment: `The other rule is I can't create global variables.`

Comment: Nothing needs to be global, just create a main funcion or other functions.

Comment: Shouldn't `state = "".join(["-" for x in range(len(word))])` be `state = "-"*len(word)`?

Comment: Thanks. Both answer work great, but I like yours a little bit better because it's nice and short :) I just don't understand what `state = list(state)` does, could you explain it to me, thanks.

Comment: `state` contains current correct guesses, EG: `electr----y`, to be able to replace `-` with a correct `guess` we need to _convert the string in to a list_. This is done by with `list(state)`. At the end of the function, we convert it back to a string by joining each item in the list: `"".join(state)`

Answer (score 2):

Expanded on SLACKY's answer by using state as the container for the valid guesses.

```
def maskWord(state, word, guess):

    result = ''
    guessed = []
    character = ''
    for character in state:
        if not character == '-':
            if not character in guessed:
                guessed.append(character)

    if not guess in guessed:
        guessed.append(guess)

    for guess in word:
        if guess in guessed:
            result += guess
        else: 
            result += "-"

    # for debugging change to if True:
    if False:
        print 'state %s' % state
        print 'word %s' % word
        print 'guess %s' % guess
        print guessed

    return result


# Lets test if it works..:
import sys

word = "electricity"
state = ""
tries = 0

loop = True
while loop:
    if tries == len(word)*3: 
        print "Fail..."
        loop = False
    else:
        guess = raw_input("Guess: ")
        tries +=1
        state = maskWord(state, word, guess)
        print state
        if maskWord(state, word, guess) == word:    
            print "WIN, WIN!!"
            loop = False
```

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
import random
import string
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
CONSONANTS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
HAND_SIZE = 7
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = { 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2,
    'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10,
    'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10 }

def load_words():
    
print ("Loading word list from file...")
    
# making the file
    
words_file= open("N:\Problem Set 1\words.txt", 'r', 0)
    
# making the wordlist
   
 words = []
   
 for line in words_file:
        
words.append(line.strip().lower())
    
print ("  ", len(words), "words loaded.")
    
return words


def get_frequency_dict(sequence):
    
# freqs: dictionary (element_type -> int)
    
frequencies = {}
    for x in sequence:
        frequencies[x] = frequencies.get(x,0) + 1
    return frequencies


# -----------------------------------


def get_word_score(word, n):
    output = 0
    # Checking whether the latter is in the list
    for letter in word:
        output = output + SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.get(letter)
    output = output * len(word)
    if len(word) == n:
        output = output + 50
    if output < 0:
        print "That's is a negative value!"
    return output
  


def display_hand(hand):
    # Displaying the hand
    for letter, frequency in hand.items():
        for i in range(frequency):
            print letter,
    print '\n'
            
def deal_hand(n):
    hand={}
    number_vowels = n / 3
    
    for i in range(number_vowels):
        z = VOWELS[random.randrange(0,len(VOWELS))]
        hand[z] = hand.get(z, 0) + 1
        
    for i in range(number_vowels, n):    
        z = CONSONANTS[random.randrange(0,len(CONSONANTS))]
        hand[z] = hand.get(z, 0) + 1
        
    return hand

# Updating the hand
def update_hand(hand, word):       
    for letter in word:
        if hand[letter] != 0:
            hand[letter] = hand.get(letter, 0) - 1 
    return hand

#If letter chosen is in hand then append
def is_valid_word(word, hand, words_file):
    handchosen = dict.copy(hand)
    first_hand =[]
    second_hand = []
    for letter in handchosen.keys():
        for f in range(handchosen[letter]):
            first_hand.append(letter)
    for letter in word:
        for s in handchosen:
            if s == letter and handchosen[letter] != 0:
                    handchosen[letter] = handchosen.get(letter, 0) - 1
    for letter in handchosen.keys():
        for f in range(handchosen[letter]):
            second_hand.append(letter)
    if words_file.count(word) > 0 and len(word) + len(second_hand) == len(first_hand):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Play the hand
def play_hand(hand, words_file):
    print
    print
    print 'Hey welcome to the Wordgame!'
    print
    print "Press '.' when you want to end the game."
    print
    n = HAND_SIZE
    old_hand = hand.copy()
    print 'Initial hand:',
    display_hand(hand)
    print
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        yourscore = 0
        numLetters = 1
        while numLetters > 0:
            quit = '.'
            word = raw_input('Please enter a valid word: ')  
            if word != quit:
                if is_valid_word(word, hand, words_file) == False:
                    print 'Invalid word. Please enter a valid word:' 
                else:
                    numLetters = 1
                    print 'You got points for:',word,'=',get_word_score(word, n)
                    yourscore = yourscore + get_word_score(word, n)
                    print 'The total score:', yourscore
                    updated_hand = update_hand(hand, word)
                    print 'Current Hand:',
                    display_hand(updated_hand)
                    print
                    hand = updated_hand
                    for num in dict.values(hand):
                        numLetters = num + numLetters
                    numLetters = numLetters - 1
                    print numLetters,'letters are still remaining.'
                    if numLetters == 0:
                        loop = 0
                    print
            else:
                numLetters,loop = 0,0
    print 'Lets see what the final score is: ', yourscore

#Play the game
def play_game(words_file):
    hand = deal_hand(HAND_SIZE) # random init
    while True:
        # Let the user make a choice
        A = raw_input('Enter n to deal a new hand, r to play the same hand or e to end game: ')
        if A == 'n':
            hand = deal_hand(HAND_SIZE)
            play_hand(hand.copy(), words_file)
            old_hand = hand.copy()
            print
        # User can take the same hand
        elif A == 'r':
            play_hand(old_hand, words_file)
        # Break
        elif A == 'e':
            break
        else:
            print "That is a invalid command."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    words_file = load_words()
    play_game(words_file)
```

Comment: I am not sure the function `load_words` will work as expected, indentation needs a reformatting.